# Date Statement Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not a SQL expert at all...we are trying to us the following to pull data from the previous week.  I am fairly certain the 4 is incorrect, as we want data from Sunday through Saturday. The statement that was created was:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
Where [Date] Between DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),0) AND
                     DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),4)
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (SQL Server?)

Comment: Yes we are using SQL Server.

Comment: We have 5 different offices and we are trying to query a revenue table to come back with the revenue for the previous week.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working on Sql Server, you can use cte structure like below, set regarding data into cte and filter in your main query:

```
;with cte (ID) as ( --data from previous week only 
  Select Id from table
  Where [Date] >= DATEADD(WEEK,-1,DATEADD(week,datediff(week,0,getdate()),0))
   AND  [Date] < DATEADD(week,datediff(week,0,getdate()),0)
)
select *
from table t
inner join cte on t.Id = cte.ID
where DATEPART(DW, [Date]) >= 0 --sunday
  and DATEPART(DW, [Date]) <= 6 --saturday
```

In the filter, edit 0 and 6 to filter your data based on date as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this, it returns previous Saturday and Sunday:

```
SELECT DATENAME(DW,(DATEADD(day, -6, getdate()))) ,DATENAME(DW,(DATEADD(day, -5, 
getdate())))

[![Day Name][1]][1]
```

So, for example, you can use DATEADD(day, -6, getdate()) to get Saturday.